# Where are the attributes for room mailbox stored?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, ldap, mailbox, resources

I'm using Exchange 2007 and I've created a room mailbox. I want to know where the settings of the room mailbox are stored? What are the attributes used to store room mailbox information? Are they stored as AD attributes? How do I view them?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just had to look up the same thing.

You can verify that an AD account has become a room mailbox by checking the following attributes:
`msExchResourceMetaData` ->  `ResourceType:Room`

`msExchResourceDisplay` -> `Room`

`msExchResourceSearchProperties` -> `Room`

If you're trying to access the actual capabilities of the room (or other room attributes), you'll need to look at either `msExchRecipientDisplayType` or `msExchResourceCapacity`. The information in these tags is not very human-readable.

Here's a related question regarding those capability attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588849/accessing-custom-resource-properties-of-a-resource-mailbox-in-active-directory

You may also wish to refer to TechNet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633491(v=exchg.150).aspx -
The section called **Resource mailbox attributes** covers these settings slightly.

(For my conference rooms in Exhcange 2010, the `msExchRecipientDisplayType` is set to `7`)

Answer (score 0):

Every Exchange mailbox is ***always*** associated with an Active Directory user object; when you create a room or resource mailbox from Exchange, a corresponding (disabled) AD user account is created. The attributes for the mailbox are stored in that user account.